# How to format an AST parse

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to format the following ast parse:

```
>>> import ast
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse('-a+b')))
Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=UnaryOp(op=USub(), operand=Name(id='a', ctx=Load())), op=Add(), right=Name(id='b', ctx=Load())))])
```

It seems like the [`indent`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html) option was introduced in python3.9, but I don't see an option to 'pretty-print' before then. What options are there to print a nicely-formatting output for an the syntax tree?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to pretty-print the AST in an earlier python version and are happy with the indent function in Python3.9 why not just take the `dump` function from 3.9 and implement it in your project? The source code is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e56d54e447694c6ced2093d2273c3e3d60b36b6f/Lib/ast.py#L111-L175

And it doesn't look very complicated and doesn't seem to use any features specific to 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

I had one use case in which I couldn't upgrade to Python 3.9 (where indent argument was added), yet I needed a way to prettify the result of `ast.dump`.

I wrote the following method that can take an unformatted `ast.dump` output and print that in a way that is easier on the eyes.

```
def prettify(ast_tree_str, indent=4):
    ret = []
    stack = []
    in_string = False
    curr_indent = 0

    for i in range(len(ast_tree_str)):
        char = ast_tree_str[i]
        if in_string and char != '\'' and char != '"':
            ret.append(char)
        elif char == '(' or char == '[':
            ret.append(char)

            if i < len(ast_tree_str) - 1:
                next_char = ast_tree_str[i+1]
                if next_char == ')' or next_char == ']':
                    curr_indent += indent
                    stack.append(char)
                    continue

            print(''.join(ret))
            ret.clear()

            curr_indent += indent
            ret.append(' ' * curr_indent)
            stack.append(char)
        elif char == ',':
            ret.append(char)

            print(''.join(ret))
            ret.clear()
            ret.append(' ' * curr_indent)
        elif char == ')' or char == ']':
            ret.append(char)
            curr_indent -= indent
            stack.pop()
        elif char == '\'' or char == '"':

            if (len(ret) > 0 and ret[-1] == '\\') or (in_string and stack[-1] != char):
                ret.append(char)
                continue

            if len(stack) > 0 and stack[-1] == char:
                ret.append(char)
                in_string = False
                stack.pop()
                continue

            in_string = True
            ret.append(char)
            stack.append(char)
        elif char == ' ':
            pass
        else:
            ret.append(char)

    print(''.join(ret))
```

Usage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    content = """
@testdecorator
def my_method(a, b):
    def ola():
        print("Hello")
    ola()
    return (a + b) * 5 + "dasdas,da'sda\\'asdas\\'\\'"
    """

    ast_tree = ast.parse(source=content)
    prettify(ast.dump(ast_tree))
```

PS.: It's not 100% equivalent to what one could get out of the Python 3.9 `ast.dump(...., indent=n)` but it should be enough for now. Feel free to improve it